# Read environment variables address in Node.js

Tags: node.js, memory

Is there a way to read environment variable address in Node.js?

For example :

```
var env_addr = env_memory_address(process.env.PATH);

console.log(env_addr); // output: 0xbf832ff
```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve by getting a memory address of an environment variable?  I'm guessing there are much better ways to solve your actual problem that might even be feasible from Javascript, but we'd need to know the real problem in order to offer ideas.  Please try not to post [xy problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you post a question about your imagined solution rather than posting about the actual problem.  You get a lot less useful info from us when you hide the actual problem.

Comment: Actually there is not have a problem. Just wondering how far Node.js can go.

Comment: So then, did my answer below answer your question?

Comment: No. But thanks again for your answer.

Comment: For an answer like how to do it :P

Comment: From plain Javascript?  Javascript does not have any ability to use memory addresses.  The language itself does not contain that capability.  I'm unsure why you don't believe that or accept that.

Comment: Maybe server side javascript does. Who knows

Comment: Server-side Javascript has the node.js C++ add-ons that I refer to in my answer.  Plain Javascript on the server doesn't have any access to memory addresses either.  It sounds like you just don't believe my answer.

Comment: You're right but im waiting for the other answers.

Comment: Man i dont keeping secrets xD i've one reason about why im writing question to here its just "wondering how far Node.js can go."

Comment: Well, the Javascript language in node.js is the same as everywhere.  It's ECMAScript.  And ECMAScript doesn't contain actual memory addresses or any way to get them or use them.  That's the language specification.  You can do pretty much anything you want in C++ add-on code in node.js, but that's not Javascript.  That's how the node.js run-time library (such as the `fs` module) is written (using C++ add-on code).

Comment: Okey. Thanks for your information. But still waiting for other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to read environment variable address in Node.js?

No, not from plain Javascript.  Javascript itself does not surface memory addresses in any way either in the browser or in the node.js execution environment.

You could probably write a node.js add-on in C++ and could then get a memory address, but even if you surfaced it back to Javascript in some Javascript data type, you couldn't do anything with it directly in Javascript (other than pass it to other C++ add-on code) and you'd probably have to put a string-ized version of the address in a Javascript string variable because there is no other Javascript data type that's a good match for a 64-bit memory address.  Or, you could make your own "handle" that had the address in it and was surfaced back to Javascript as an object.  But, either way you couldn't do anything with the memory address in Javascript.